# Cannot fill my list if i move it to new Thread

Tags: c#

I am use `SafeFileEnumerator` class to search for files inside folder root, this class return only files from location with permission so I am use it successfully.

When I try to fill my list in this way all works fine:

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
                    list = SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,
                        "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

But in this case my GUI freeze so I move it to new thread and in this case nothing happen and I wondered why:

```
private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    dialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    tbAddDir.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    string pathToSearch = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Search for pcap files...";
        groupBoxRootDirectory.Enabled = false;
        btnStart.Enabled = false;                

        ThreadStart starter = delegate
        {
            list = SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.pcap", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(starter);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();

        if(list.Count != 0)
            AddFilesToListBox(list);
    }
}
```

**SafeFileEnumerator class code:**

```
public static class SafeFileEnumerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string parentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory).SelectMany(x => EnumerateDirectories(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return directories.Concat(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }

            return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

after my list is full of files:

```
private void AddFilesToListBox(List<string> filesList)
{
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    Editcap editcap = new Editcap();
    Capinfos capinfos = new Capinfos();
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
        (s1, e1) =>
        {
            foreach (string fileName in filesList)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
                if (checkFileCreationDate(fileInfo))
                {
                    if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                    {
                        if (editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            addFileToListBox(fileInfo.FullName, capinfos.getFileDuration(fileInfo.FullName));
                        }
                        else if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileInfo.FullName))
                        {
                            fileToAdd = editcap.getNewFileName(fileInfo.FullName);

                            if (new FileInfo(fileToAdd).Exists && !fileInfo.Exists)
                            {
                                addFileToListBox(fileToAdd, capinfos.getFileDuration(fileInfo.FullName));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lvFiles.Items[lvFiles.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true; });
                toolStripStatusLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} files were added", lvFiles.Items.Count);
            }

            //this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lvFiles.Items[lvFiles.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true; });
        };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
    (s1, e1) =>
    {
        groupBoxRootDirectory.Enabled = true;
        btnClear.Enabled = true;
        if (lvFiles.Items.Count != 0)
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} files were added", lvFiles.Items.Count);

        if (tbAddDir.Text != "")
        {
            listener = new FileListener();
            listener.startListener(tbAddDir.Text);
            listener._newFileEventHandler += listener_newFileEventHandler;
        }
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "nothing happen[s]"? When you trace the code, does it not find any files when files exist? Does it find files but not show them in the UI? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: it didn't find any files although the code get into SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles method

Comment: When are you reading the values from the returned list? Are you waiting for the other thread to finish? If so, please include that code in the question.

Comment: in the case with the new thread the return list empty

Comment: Do you know if the code is throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException? Looking at the EnumerateFiles code above, that could cause the error.

Comment: no, the code did not get into the catch

Comment: could you provide the code that reads/consumes your list object?

Comment: that's all my relevant code for now, why my list is empty ?

Comment: @user1269592 that's not, actually. The relevant part of the code is the one that uses the list. If you didn't wrote it yet, then the question is: how do you test your code? Where do you put your breakpoints? I suspect you forgot the async pattern part.

Comment: see my update, AddFilesToListBox is the method who handle that list

Comment: That's not allowed.  Your code crashes but you don't check for it.  You'll need to test e.Error in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: @user1269592 Could you provide the code that calls AddFilesToListBox?

Comment: after t.start() i am call AddFilesToListBox(list);

Comment: see my update: btnAddDir_Click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after t.start() i am call AddFilesToListBox(list);

You did not implemented an [asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx).

After `t.Start();` is called, the thread did not finished its work yet, so your list was still empty at the time you called `AddFilesToListBox`. Do implement an async pattern and call `AddFilesToListBox` once the thread finished its job.

Comment: i try t.Join(); and its works fine, is it the correct way to do it ?

Comment: @user1269592 I fixed the link. It's not hard to implement, but I recommend you to have a look at the different possibilities (see the link) before trying to write code.

Comment: @user1269592 I wouldn't use join here, as it's blocking the calling thread. A simple event-based async pattern would probably be more appropriated.